# Load Pictures from the WP memory

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I was wondering on what type of code should I write in order to be able to select a photo from the Camera Roll of the Windows Phone. Any idea?

I would appreciate it if someone could help. I'm participating in a competition at the university ...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is to use the `PhotoChooserTask`. You can find more information and examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

If you want more control (and don't mind writing more code), you can also access the albums directly by using the `MediaLibrary` class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can't select a photo from the library in any way programmatically. Windows Phone only lets you prompt the user with a choice so that he will select it from the camera roll. You don't have any control of the screen where the user chooses, you merely launch the task and it returns you a photo the user has chosen.

That said, you could select a picture with the PhotoChooserTask, included in the Microsoft.Phone.Tasks library. Alternatively, it's common to also see a Camera Capture Task (when the user takes a photo instead of choosing one) in places where users are presented with the option to select a photo. Examples for the Camera Capture are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394006%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
...
PhotoChooserTask selectphoto = null;
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
selectphoto = new PhotoChooserTask();
selectphoto.Completed += new EventHandler(selectphoto_Completed);
selectphoto.Show();
}
void selectphoto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
{
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(e.ChosenPhoto);
image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(e.OriginalFileName));
}
}
```